# preference not working ios watch

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, apple-watch

I have developing an ios watch app. I want to pass a value to ios watch. i have try several methods. When storing value in a element of ios app. I am using xcode 8 and the code is written in swift.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webview: UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        print("webview")
        let url = URL (string: "http://www.google.com/")
        let request = URLRequest(url: url!)
        webview.loadRequest(request)

        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let currentLevel = "cl"
        let currentLevelKey = "currentLevel"
        preferences.set(currentLevel, forKey: currentLevelKey)
        preferences.synchronize()
        print("pref")
    }

}
```

Then i have call the preference in ios watch app the code is
**InterfaceController.swift**

```
class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBAction func clickingTheButton() {
        print("clicked")
        let preferences = UserDefaults.standard
        let currentLevelKey = "currentLevel"

        if preferences.object(forKey: currentLevelKey) == nil {
            // Doesn't exist
            print("Doesn't exist")
        } else {
            let currentLevel = preferences.integer(forKey: currentLevelKey)
            print("preference : ",currentLevel)
        }
    }

}
```

How to pass value from ios to watch app. Please help me.

Comment: after one google search and 2 clicks : https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchconnectivity/wcsession/1615621-updateapplicationcontext

Comment: I didn't get the correct answer. can u explain how to implement the code.

Comment: We I've never created a watch app so not really, but Apple give a lot of documentation to read, start from there. There's probably a lot of tutorials too, just search a bit, or wait for someone to pop here and give you an answer

Comment: You have to use the WatchConnectivity framework to pass data from the iOS app to the Watch app.